# Procedimiento para alta de usuarios enjaulados y subida a carpeta www

Tags: apache, sftp

Estaba creando un pequeño howto para dar de alta usuarios enjaulados que puedan subir y modificar ficheros en una carpeta dentro de /var/www 
Me gustaría que vieran si es un procedimiento válido y seguro, o si se nos escapa algo, o si hay otras alternativas a esto.

Trabajamos sobre RedHat/Centos 7.

Primero editamos el fichero /etc/ssh/sshd_config y comentamos la siguiente linea:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Luego agregamos las siguientes lineas:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp_group
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Y reiniciamos el servicio SSH

```
$ systemctl restart sshd
```

Una vez preparado el servicio SFTP, lanzamos las siguientes lineas:

```
$ USUARIO=DEVUser
$ groupadd sftp_group
$ useradd $USUARIO 
$ usermod -g sftp_group -s /bin/false $USUARIO
$ chmod 777 /home/$USUARIO
$ chown root:root /home/$USUARIO
$ chmod go-w /home/$USUARIO
$ mkdir /home/$USUARIO/site
$ chmod 644 /home/$USUARIO/site
$ chmod ug+rwX /home/$USUARIO/site
$ chown $USUARIO:sftp_group /home/$USUARIO/site
```

Le damos una contraseña al usuario creado:

```
$ passwd $USUARIO
```

Editamos el fichero /etc/fstab y agreramos la siguiente linea, para que monte dentro de la carpeta del usuario, la carpeta donde está el contenido web en modo espejo y así pueda tener acceso:

```
#Usuarios enjaulados
/var/www/sitioweb /home/DEVUser/site none bind,rw
```

Y para finalizar, como el usuario DEVUser que pertenece al grupo sftp_group y para que pueda añadir y modificar ficheros que luego tengan que ser leídos por el usuario apache:

```
$ setfacl -R -d -m u:apache:rwx /var/www/sitioweb
$ setfacl -R -d -m g:apache:rwx /var/www/sitioweb
$ setfacl -R -m u:DEVUser:rwx /var/www/sitioweb
```

Hice pruebas de subida de ficheros con el usuario dado de alta, y funciona correctamente, pero no sabemos si este sería el procedimiento correcto para este caso. Si es correcto, aquí lo dejo para todo el mundo que quiera implementar algo similar.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Xavs! Creo que para que sea más útil y fácil de aprovechar a la comunidad, deberías plantear tu howto en el formato pregunta-respuesta. ¿Podrías editarla y añadir la respuesta? Saludos!